# Redirect based on a query string

Tags: .htaccess

is this query correct for redirecting example.com/?abcd2 to example.com/abcd2.php

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?abcd2$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/abcd2.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

No there are some minor glitches. Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^abcd2$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/abcd2.php? [R=301,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` value doesn't start with `?` and you need `?` in target URI to strip off existing query string.